Denial of Service during Initial Block Download
I'm certain this has an obvious answer, but I haven't been able to find it -
Since it doesn't cost a transaction fee to request block data from another node, what stops an attacker from (D)DoSing a node with spurious GetBlocks?
Relatedly: why would a node bother to spend its bandwidth fulfilling GetBlocks requests when it would help a competing node?

Nodes don’t compete. It is in the interest of node operators to spread the current state of the blockchain to help that all participants converge on a shared state. For many node operators, their bandwidth allowance exceeds the demand they encounter, so sharing the blockchain is basically free to them. You could absolutely request the entire blockchain from one peer over and over again. If this attack were to spread, people would probably limit the amount of bandwidth they permit to be used for uploading by setting the startup option maxuploadtarget.
